# pipe Windows windows to Xserver on my linux host

Tags: windows, x-server

Is it possible to pipe a native graphical Windows application to Xserver?

I would like to run a virtual machine on my Linux host and  access the application directly. (Something like the seamless  function from VirtualBox)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you can get to that, as far as I know, is using [`rdesktop`](http://www.rdesktop.org/).

You need a server-side application to get seamless mode applications though. (Plain RDP session doesn't require anything on the Windows host.)